# geofencing for multiple region for xamarin ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, geofencing

I need entry and exit notification in my app. so I have written below code for the same and it is working as expected. but i want to check for multiple overlay or region.

for an example i have set of 3 overlay or region with specific coordinates. i want to check entry and exit for the region **near by user's current location**.

```
            if (pointregion.ContainsCoordinate(location.Coordinate) && Entryregion == false)
            {
                Entryregion = true; Exitregion = false;
                ShowNotification("You are just in " + pointregionname + " region", "Alert");
            }
            if (!pointregion.ContainsCoordinate(location.Coordinate) && Entryregion == true)
            {
                Entryregion = false; Exitregion = true;
                ShowNotification("You are just left " + pointregionname + " region", "Alert");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe make use of `CLLocation​Manager`'s region monitoring and set up geofencing regions.

1. Create a list of `CLCircularRegion` or other `CLRegion` type.
2. Add all the regions by calling `locationManager.StartMonitoring(yourRegion)` for each region.
3. When you are done with a specific region remove it by calling`locationManager.StopMonitoring(yourRegion)`

Then when a region is entered or left the `RegionLeft(CLLocationManager manager, CLRegion region)` or `RegionEntered(CLLocationManager manager, CLRegion region)` delegate methods will be called. You will need to override these methods in a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` class.